# Angular main bundle size issue

Tags: angular, webpack

I am currently having some problems with my main bundle size.

I added a lazy loading module for some components and I checked the extra chunk has been created for this. However, those modules such as TranslateModule I import in my lazy loading module increase the size of the main bundle. Is this normal behavior? or am I missing some build option?

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [SomeComponent],
  imports: [CommonModule, TranslateModule] // if I add some module, it increases the size of main bundle
})
export class SomeLazyModule {}
```

Comment: If you lazy load the module then don’t import it like this in the modules that aren’t loaded lazy. You should import it via lazy with dynamic import syntax. And have NONE regular import to it in any file that isn’t loaded lazy.

Comment: @RazRonen hmm how do I import those common modules in module file then? I am only lazyloading that SomeLazyModule in router as loadChildren: () => import('./someLazy/some-lazy.module').then(m => m.SomeLazyModule)

Comment: That does it for you. All the exported components from your lazy modules will be accessible in all the declared modules of the router module that import the lazy module.

Comment: my issue is not about access, but about the increased size of the main bundle when I import an additional module in that lazy-loaded module file.

Comment: That is enough to import: import('./someLazy/some-lazy.module'). Webpack will separate it to another chunk

Comment: Don’t have any other imports to this module